# mathematica:: 3d piecwise function problem

Tags: functions, mathematica

i'm trying to plot a function  $$\ f(x,y)=cos(\sqrt{x^2 +y^2})$$,same as cos(r).. f(x,y)=0 for points ,which are on circle.when the points are out of this circle i want the function f(x,y) to be 0 as well. so the support of my function  to be the circle.i want to plot this situation.. as i thought, my function is 
  $$f(x,y)=
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
cos(r) ,r<\pi/2\\ 
0,othervise \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
but my plot isn't continuous...please help me understand the problem.-->
[image]-->
[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a feature to indicate that your function is not continuous there. You can use the `Exclusions` option to prevent it

```
k[x_, y_] := With[{r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]},
  Piecewise[{{Cos[r], r < Pi/2}}, 0]
]
Plot3D[k[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Edit

If you are wondering why this plot looks a bit bumpy at the bottom, the reason is that there are too few polygons used to create a sharp plot. You can try

```
Plot3D[k[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Exclusions -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 6]
```

and then you clearly see your circle at the bottom

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks, now i have this plot.but don't understand why isn't support  circle? my solution must be  my plot just without breaking..and this looks a little , different cause i don't see the circle on the xoy flat

Comment: looks exactly what i needed, thank you very much .

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with $\texttt{Piecewise[]}$. Try this variation instead:

$\texttt{f[x_, y_] := With[{r = Sqrt[x*x + y*y]}, If[r > Pi/2, 0, Cos@r]];}$
$\texttt{Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]}$

[image]

You can use the option $\texttt{PlotPoints -> 100}$
to make the base sharper, but using
$\texttt{Piecewise[]}$ leaves a gap in the plot surface as you noticed.

Comment: thank you for your comment , but still got the same plot :(

Comment: thanks for uploading..but as i thought f(x,y) must me nonzero on the circle with radius pi/2..my problem is to see this picture ..but this plot doesn't seem so..am i wrong with constructing the function?

Comment: You are wrong as the plot shows. If $r=\pi/2$ then $\cos(r)=0$.

Comment: r=π/2 is the points (x,y) which  satisfy the x^2+y^2=(π/2)^2 so they are the circle points....and the cos must be zero on this circle points..